# Why does my 2012 Subaru Exiga lags when I am moving off from a stationary position?

Tags: subaru, acceleration

Does not pick up speed for a couple seconds. I changed the throttle sensor about a year ago when I had the issue and the problem went away for a while. There is also a check engine light and flashing cruise light as well.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you replaced the throttle sensor, did you perform a "relearn" on it?